# Menu problem when web host upgraded from CPanel to Site Tools

Tags: civicrm.settings.php, menu, drupal-7

Recently, my host provider [Siteground](https://siteground.com) upgraded the back-end of my site from using a classic **CPanel** to the new and improved **Site Tools**. Upon the upgrade, the main CiviCRM 5.34.0 menu no longer appeared in my Drupal 7.78 instance. Also, icons with **?** showed up as unknown boxes. After getting assistance at [chat.civicrm.org](https://chat.civicrm.org), the problem was solved...

Answer (score 3):

I replaced the full URLs in the *civicrm.settings.php* file with relative URLs as shown below:

**FROM**

> global $civicrm_root;
> $civicrm_root = '/home/customer/www/example.org/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm';
> if (!defined('CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR')) {
> define( 'CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR', '/home/customer/www/example.org/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/');
> }

**TO**

> global $civicrm_root;
> $civicrm_root = './sites/all/modules/civicrm';
> if (!defined('CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR')) {
> define( 'CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR', './sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/');
> }

Comment: This got my site going again, so was invaluable.  But it could not find the extensions folder despite this being the default, so I ended up uninstalling & re-installing them. Did you have this problem?  (PS. I couldn't see anything 'improved' about Site Tools!

Comment: Andy, I did not have this problem. The extensions folder remained in the expected place and I was able to access those extensions as I did normally. The jump to Site Tools did take some getting used to, but it's definitely a more secure environment. However, with the loss of the cPanel, I did learn more about ssh and having a command prompt to have quicker access to files and whatnot.